# Restructure the date in multiple columns at the same time in R

Tags: r, list, date, lapply, posixlt

I have multiple data frames, each of which represents data from the year 2016 - 2019 (i.e., df.16, df.17, df.18, df.19), and I would like to transform the `date` column in each from `YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00` to simply show the month. I'd like to accomplish this by making a new column `month` and doing this concurrently to all dataframes. I *think* I thould use `lapply` although I am not entire sure. My code is as follows:

Making the list:
`df.list <- list(df.16, df.17, df.18, df.19, df.20)`

Applying the function:
`lapply(df.list, function(x) {x$month <- month(date); x})`

However, I continually get the following error: `Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) :  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve the problem:

`new_df_list <- lapply(df.list, function(df)  within(df, month <- month(date)))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `transform` where we don't have to use the anonymous function

```
new_df_list <- lapply(df.list, transform, month = month(date))
```